# R caret genetic algorithm control number of final features

Tags: r, r-caret

Is there a way to control the number of features selected by the GA algorithm in caret? I tried setting the vars parameter which is mentioned in gafs_initial(), which I believe is inherited by gafs(), but I this does not seem to be the way to control it.

```
ctrl <- gafsControl(functions = caretGA,
    verbose = T,
    allowParallel = T,
    metric=c(internal='Rsquared',external='RMSE'),
    maximize = c(internal = TRUE, external = FALSE))

ga <- gafs(x = x, 
            y = y,
            iters = 25,
                vars=5,
            gafsControl = ctrl,            
            method = "lm")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gafs` doesn't let you fix the number of variables in the subset. You could try to coerce it by adding a desirability function for this though. See [this example](https://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-using-genetic-algorithms.html#the-example-revisited) of using desirability functions for a different purpose in `gafs`